# Текст до кнопки "Подробнее"

Tags: php

Приветствую. Раз я нашел такой полезный сайт, я буду тут всех мучить :).

У меня на сайте идёт вывод статей. А в базе приходиться создавать специально две строки в таблице - "Текст" и "Описание" (которое идёт до кнопки <<Подробнее>>). Как сделать, чтобы из "Текста" выводить какое-то определённое количество символов или слов (а не задействовать несколько лишних строк в базе). Надеюсь внятно объяснил :).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @GLAGOLA ^_^ я уже решил проблему) но спасибо что ответили с примером и подробно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логично предположить, что до кнопки "Подробнее" должен располагаться целый абзац (или несколько), а скажем не пол предложения, поэтому необходимо определиться какое кол-во абзацев вы хотите видеть до кн. "Подробнее".

Далее запускаем скрипт (где `$text` - текст статьи, `$title` - название статьи, `$paragraph_count` - кол-во параграфов перед "Подробнее", предположим абзацы в БД хранятся обрамленные тэгом `<p>...</p>`):

```
$title = 'Some article';

$text = <<<TEXT
<p>These escaped characters are not very useful for outputting to a web page because     HTML ignore extra white space.</p> 
<p> A tab, newline, and carriage return are all examples of extra (ignorable) white     space.</p> 
<p>However, when writing to a file that may be read by human eyes these escaped     characters are a valuable tool!</p>
TEXT;

$paragraph_count = 3;

if (preg_match_all('/\<p\>.*?\<\/p\>/', $text, $matches))
{
    echo 'Название статьи - '.$title.'<br />';   
    echo implode('', array_slice($matches[0], 0, $paragraph_count));

    echo ' Подробнее >>>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то вопрос составлен некорректно, и не понять, что именно нужно вам. Если правильно понял:

```
 echo mb_substr($sql['txt'],0,20,"UTF-8").'..'
 echo '<a href="#">Подробнее...</a>';
```